# What is significance of omitting 'url(' in Django urlpatterns

Tags: python, django

I have been given some Django code to take over where some of the entries in the urlpatterns in the settings.py use url() and some don't as can be seen here:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')), 
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^movies/', include('movies.urls')),
    (r'^profile/', include('userprofile.urls')),
    (r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^trailer/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='trailer.html'), name='trailer'),
    url(r'^newuser/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='trailer.html'), name='activate'), 
    url(r'^abcd123/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='trailer.html'), name='url_login'), 
    url(r'^fb/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='fb.html'), name='fb'), 
)
```

Does it make any difference whether or not `url(` is used? Is there a recommended standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples are the old (deprecated) way for specifying url patterns.

In your case, with the version of Django you are using, it does not make any difference if you use tuples or `url()`s.

Also note that, since Django 1.8, the call to `patterns()` is no longer required and [has been deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#patterns). Django 1.8 [recommends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#syntax-of-the-urlpatterns-variable) using a list of `url()`s instead.

Comment: Django 1.8 still supports `patterns()` and raw tuples, they are "only" deprecated as of now.

Comment: @dhke: that's what I wrote :)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a full example of how you'd do it in Django 1.8 (and forward), using a list of tuples, as mentioned. 1.8 is a long-term release, so upgrading to 1.8 will guarantee you security releases for at least three years.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')), 
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^movies/', include('movies.urls')),
    url(r'^profile/', include('userprofile.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^trailer/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='trailer.html'), name='trailer'),
    url(r'^newuser/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='trailer.html'), name='activate'), 
    url(r'^abcd123/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='trailer.html'), name='url_login'), 
    url(r'^fb/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='fb.html'), name='fb'), 
]
```

You can also remove `patterns` from your `import` list at that time.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it make any difference whether or not `url(` is used?

No. Passing a `list` or a `tuple` is treated in the same way as if the arguments where wrapped in `url()`:

*`django/urls/__init__.py`*:

```
 if isinstance(t, (list, tuple)):                                      
     t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)
 elif isinstance(t, RegexURLPattern):
     t.add_prefix(prefix)
```

> Is there a recommended standard?

Use `url()`.

`config.urls.patterns()` itself is scheduled for deprecation in django 1.10, at which point, `urlpatterns` must be a list of `url()` instances and raw tuples cannot be used anymore.

Also: [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).